# What is a Rotary Club Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Rotary Club Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Rotary Club Words™ | Not Rotary Club Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ANT | FLY |
| ASH | CINDERS |
| DEN | CAVE |
| CHAR | BURN |
| INCH | METER |
| DYED | TINTED |
| RELY | TRUST |
| LOYAL | TRUE |
| ANGLE | VEER |
| CEDAR | PINE |
| ELBOW | KNEE |
| VERSE | POETRY |
| STABLE | UNSTABLE |
| ALPINE | LOFTY |
| ERRING | PERFECT |
| STRIPE | SOLID |
| TOOLBARS | ICONS |
| PRINTOUTS | HARDCOPY |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Rotary Club Words™,Not Rotary Club Words™
ANT,FLY
ASH,CINDERS
DEN,CAVE
CHAR,BURN
INCH,METER
DYED,TINTED
RELY,TRUST
LOYAL,TRUE
ANGLE,VEER
CEDAR,PINE
ELBOW,KNEE
VERSE,POETRY
STABLE,UNSTABLE
ALPINE,LOFTY
ERRING,PERFECT
STRIPE,SOLID
TOOLBARS,ICONS
PRINTOUTS,HARDCOPY
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Rotary Club Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Rotary Club Words™, many more exist.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every Rotary Club Word can be:

> Converted to another word by rotating part of the end to the beginning:

So

> ANT -> TAN
>  ASH -> HAS
>  DEN -> END
>  CHAR -> ARCH
>  INCH -> CHIN
>  DYED -> EDDY
>  RELY -> LYRE
>  LOYAL -> ALLOY
>  ANGLE -> GLEAN
>  CEDAR -> ARCED
>  ELBOW -> BOWEL
>  VERSE -> SEVER
>  STABLE -> ABLEST
>  ALPINE -> PINEAL
>  ERRING -> RINGER
>  STRIPE -> RIPEST
>  TOOLBARS -> BARSTOOL
>  PRINTOUTS -> OUTSPRINT

Comment: I hoped that would last a *little* longer - nice job! :)